# To draw arrowed line DOJO?

Tags: dojo

How to draw a arrowed line in dojo..

```
            group.createPath()
            .moveTo(len-_arrowHeight,0)
            .lineTo(len-_arrowHeight,-_arrowWidth)
            .lineTo(len,0)
            .lineTo(len-_arrowHeight,_arrowWidth)
            .lineTo(len-_arrowHeight,0)
            .setStroke( _defaultStroke)
            .setFill('#6038aa')
            ;
```

Any other way to draw using any api

Comment: grid.createLine({x1:100,y1 :90,x2 :150,y2 : 90}).setStroke({color : "#ff0000"});  How to add the arrow to the line

Comment: Why you looking for another way?.. Is it not working?

Answer (score -1):

Are you sure you need Dojo javascript just for the arrow?

You can do arrows in pure CSS. There are even [online generators for that (link)](http://apps.eky.hk/css-triangle-generator/).

Comment: @Downvoter doesn't seem to like more than one way to skin a chicken.